# timeit returning a negative value occasionally, possible bug in timeit

Tags: python, time

I have worked on [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net) problems and decided to add timing, so added `timeit` to time `main()` via the following snippet (storing global `RESULT` in  `main()` for convenience)

```
t = timeit.timeit(main, 'gc.enable()', number=1)
print("# Euler", PROBLEM, ".py RESULT: ", RESULT))
```

Works fine. But, some run so fast I thought I could do this.

```
t = timeit.timeit(main, 'gc.enable()', number=1)
if (t < 0.001):
    t2 = timeit.timeit(main, 'gc.enable()', number=1000)
```

And it works sometimes. However if I run this repeatedly I sometime gets negative values for t2. Using Euler #2 for example I get these results from running this 5 times in a row.

```
# Euler2.py RESULT: 4613732  3.17869758716347e-05 seconds
repeats timing  -3.7966224778973e-05 sec per call

# Euler2.py RESULT: 4613732  3.1558464885145785e-05 seconds
repeats timing  2.4836235955056177e-05 sec per call

# Euler2.py RESULT: 4613732  3.131149340411519e-05 seconds
repeats timing  -3.5684903805855466e-05 sec per call

# Euler2.py RESULT: 4613732  3.177450256451194e-05 seconds
repeats timing  2.4558941864410162e-05 sec per call

# Euler2.py RESULT: 4613732  3.158939868681022e-05 seconds
repeats timing  2.4268726425449536e-05 sec per call
```

Now if I change the repeat count to 100,000 or more I don't see negative t2 values at all and the time per call is consistently around 2.4e-5 sec per call.

If I repeated 10,000 times I see new behavior. t2 is consistently positive, but the values bounce around a lot. For 10 runs I get

```
repeats timing  2.4194581894745244e-05 sec per call
repeats timing  1.8200670315524775e-05 sec per call
repeats timing  2.4408832248987168e-05 sec per call
repeats timing  2.4378118077314547e-05 sec per call
repeats timing  1.8361976570139902e-05 sec per call
repeats timing  1.8055080028738498e-05 sec per call
repeats timing  1.8102133534236732e-05 sec per call
repeats timing  2.4485323058654477e-05 sec per call
repeats timing  3.118363087991698e-05 sec per call
repeats timing  1.803846408685413e-05 sec per call
```

Finally, set the repeat count to 1000 and removed the initial (repeat=1) timeit. Same time of result, some negatives and a lot of bounce.

I repeated this set using Python 2.7, similar result -- everything else was version 3.4

To me, this looks like a bug in the timeit feature when the total time is on the same order as the system timer interrupt, but I thought perhaps I was missing something.

ADDED

I should also add that I know about other timer functions including perf_counter().

I am asking specifically about timeit() because I thought it to be an easy to use hi-hres timer that I could use in new and old versions of python and would like to continue to do so if it can be trusted.

ADDED

Based on the answer provided, I changed my timing code to be bsaed on pef_counter() and sure enough, I got negative values sometimes too. So, small timing increments are simply not reliable if you use on old window box. That's what I wanted to know. What make me think it was in the Python stack was that for the very small timings, the values seemed accurate. Should have guessed it was the combination of Windows and device drivers.

Comment: Are you running Windows? On a older processor?

Comment: Yeah, my laptop was so stolen, so I am using an old Windows XP SP3  with an Athlon 64 X2 dual core 3800+ at the moment.

Comment: Simple: gather the negative time intervals you show above until you have enough to get back to before your laptop was stolen and prevent the theft.

Comment: I liked you answer msw, but still would like to know if timeit can be used reliably. The docs for this function seem to suggest accurate timings, but I suspect that was based on numerous repeats of a snippet. Still, negative values seem unlikely without time travel or buggy code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows, timeit by default uses `time.clock` as its time source, which in turn uses the Windows API `QueryPerformanceCounter`. Depending on the version of Windows and the capabilities of the machine `QueryPerformanceCounter` uses the processor's time stamp counter (TSC) as a timer. A number of older multiprocessor machines weren't able to keep the TSC in sync between processors and didn't report this correctly to Windows, or had bugs trying to do so. This results in `QueryPerformanceCounter` returning results that appear to jump around as the process gets executed on different processors.

Microsoft has a long detailed description of the problem on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408(v=vs.85).aspx

AMD released a fix for this problem on Windows XP systems called the [AMD Dual Core Optimizer](http://support.amd.com/en-us/search/utilities).